# alphanumeric regex on a substring

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I know regex and substrings is a common question on here but i can not seem to correlate what I am reading to actual application.

**What i want to do:**

take a string, look at the last 16 characters of the string, and make sure its alphanumeric. Below is what i have come up with.

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(STRINGTOCHECK.ToLower().Substring(16), @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
```

**request**

some code showing me the right way to accomplish this

or pointing out where my code is wrong

etc.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: `Substring(16)` _starts_ the substring at that point, it doesn't start that far from the end (unless you're lucky with string length.)

Comment: what if i dont know what comes before those last 16 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the last 16 characters are alphanumeric? Just use this regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}$
```

The problem you have right now is that `.Substring(16)` will return all characters in the string after and including position 16 - *not* the last 16 characters. What's more, you're already case-insensitive, so:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(STRINGTOCHECK, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}$"))
```

The final `$` anchor makes sure the last 16 characters are being matched.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to `Substring` is the index from which to *start*.

So, to get a substring of the *last* 16 characters, you need to subtract 16 from the length of the string.

```
string last16 = STRINGTOCHECK.Substring(STRINGTOCHECK.Length - 16);
if(Regex.IsMatch(last16, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
{

}
```

Comment: that is what i was thinking i needed to do. is it possible to do that in one line?

Comment: @toosweetnitemare - Sure, but you loose lots of the readability. Why do it on one line that makes less sense?

Comment: i wont be managing this application after i build it. The "manger" of the code has requested i code it that way. Looks like minitech has given me that solution. Thank you for your help.